# Local static Dictionary crashes Visual Basic compiler

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

The following code immediately crashes the Visual Basic compiler in VS2005 (at least, for my environment: Windows 7):

```
Public Module foo
    Public Function FUNC() As System.Int32
        Static dict As Generic.Dictionary(Of Int32, Of String)
        Return 0
    End Function
End Module
```

Specifically, upon finishing the line that defines 'dict' (static, local dictionary). Now, I've learned to be skeptical of declaring bugs in a compiler (especially for such a simple set of code as the above), so I'm curious as to why this occurs. Obviously the inelegant crash is a limitation in VS2005, but does the crash occur due to an underlying issue with declaring a static, generic dictionary? As in, is this bad/illegitimate VB?

Comment: I can provide more information regarding my environment here, for those curious. I left it out of my question since it isn't strictly relevant to the legitimacy of the vb code.

Comment: I've never needed static local variables in more than 10 years of VB.NET development. Look what happens behind the scenes: http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/pages/7717.aspx

Comment: @Tim: It strikes me as a useful abstraction, though I'm suspicious of it. As it stands, though, I need a single data-set across all calls of a method, and that data-set needs only to be accessed by that method. Declaring it as a local, static variable limits its scope to only that which is necessary, which seems preferable over ticking it as global. I appreciate the link though

Comment: @usr: In this instance, VS2005 crashes to desktop. 'Would you like to send information to Micrsoft' and all the rest.

Comment: @TimSchmelter So the compiler is clever and generates code. Good! That's no reason to avoid a feature. I hope you use closures? They aren't supported in IL, so the compiler [generates entire classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/02/686456.aspx)! Similarly with the new Async features in VS 2012. Let the compiler do the heavy lifting. Your source code is shorter and simpler, and you become more productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer. The dictionary definition should be Generic.Dictionary(Of X, Y) rather than (Of X, Of Y).

Comment: Can you be more specific what the answer is and maybe even _why_?

Comment: Seems to just be syntax. The code that causes the error is incorrect; one too many 'Of's.

Comment: Oh, i've overlooked that :) But shouldn't this be just a compiler error?

Comment: You'd think. =p Seems like a pretty glaring oversight

Comment: Has anyone reported the bug? You can report online at Microsoft Connect. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio